# Technology behind Twitter's new mobile web experience

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile, mobile-website

I just saw Twitter has a new mobile web experience. It looks really nice. Do you know what libraries or frameworks they used to accomplish this type of experience? Specifically CSS/JavaScript based frameworks.

I am shopping around for mobile web frameworks to use on my next project. So I am particularly interested in what the big guys are doing.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if they were using their own framework for their mobile web site

Answer (score 1):

Twitter are indeed using their own framework. If you look at the source you can see it. They have one of the most advanced mobile sites on the web.

I work in mobile development and can tell you that there are very few frameworks out there that are usable for medium to large scale projects. We tried jQuery Mobile which was too bloated and slow and gives you no control over your application. We also looked at Sencha Touch and a number of the other smaller frameworks. I don't want to put these projects down, as it's very early days yet and there will be improvements but none of them performed.

In the end we went with writing our own framework as well and it's benefited us greatly. We have full control over everything, we can optimise the css transitions and style everything easily the way it should look.

Comment: Okay, so if they built their own framework, can you talk about the techniques they probably utilized in order to build this framework? Links to any articles/resources would also be very helpful.